#  is posible with ASP.NET Dynamic Data Generating the code of form separately

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, subsonic, scaffolding

is posible with ASP.NET Dynamic Data Generating the code of form separately? to edit the form separately

thanks

Comment: You can start by being more clear about what you're asking for. What forms are you referring to? Where are they stored?

Comment: I still have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you're asking for... the short answer is No.

What we'd like is a '**generated** scaffold' that is built from a current data structure and provides actual webforms and their related files which can then be modified as we see fit.

The current Dynamic data infrastructure is different.  It' doesn't generate the code for every form/listing page.  The pages are always dynamically generated.  Developers only have the ability to "extend" the dynamically generated form  which isn't as easy as it should be.

An example of modifying the dynamic form is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723645(VS.100).aspx

Currently, we have dynamic routes. IE.  {table}/{action}.aspx.  I'd like the ability to physically generate the files, and modify them from there.

You can read more here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1453909.aspx/1?Generate+Source+Code